# What is the most up to date way to compile code quotations in F#

Tags: compilation, f#, quotations

I'm building a symbolic derivative engine. For example

```
let f = <@ fun x:double -> x * x @>
let df = der f
```

and the resulting expression will be

```
<@ 2 * x @>
```

The actual equations could be arbitrarily complex.

The generation of the derivatives are not too hard using recursive
pattern matching and transformations but in the end I want to use
the generated equations in tight numerical loops as if I had hand
written them. This is numerical computing code so faster is always
better ( if possible )

I've looked at the FSharpX quotation compiler but it looks like an interpreter rather than a compiler.

Comment: I also know maple, matlab, pylab and calculus by pen and paper. My question was about compiling code quotations.

Comment: My suggestion was that you might wish to use languages that inherently support symbolic manipulation, instead of trying to implement it in other languages.

Comment: Also - many people have previously asked this. Just search on Google or StackOverflow.

Comment: Again please note my question is about code quotation compilation not specifically about symbolic math. Yes I know I can do symbolic math in other languages. That is beyond the point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not tested this, but the code that translates F# quotations to LINQ expressions (and compiles them) has now moved from F# PowerPack into the F# Core library, so I think that is the most up-to-date version:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers

LeafExpressionConverter.EvaluateQuotation <@ 1 + 2 @>
```

and to use it for lambdas

```
let d=LeafExpressionConverter.EvaluateQuotation <@ fun y -> y+1.0 @> 
    :?> ( double -> double )

Console.WriteLine(d 10)
```

outputs

```
11
```

Note the cast at the end to convert the ''obj'' to a lambda of the correct type

Comment: Very cool new stuff. No references to this on google except the very short undescriptive doc. btw if I had EvaluateQuotation <@ fun y -> y + 1 @> for example I get returned type obj. How to convert this to a proper lambda usable. I guess I need a cast.

Comment: I guess the obvious next question is how do LINQ expressions get converted to real code at run time vs compile time?